# finishActivity (int RequestCode) doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to close an Activity that is open from my own activity. I think finish activity is the better way but it doesn't work. Here is my code to open the activity. (Works with a third party package, this may be the problem?)

```
Intent calendar = new Intent();
calendar.setPackage("com.digibites.calendar");
if (calendar.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(calendar, REQUEST_CALENDAR);
    CURRENT_ACTIVITY = REQUEST_CALENDAR;
}
```

I close the activity with this, after launch it:

```
finishActivity(CURRENT_ACTIVITY);
```

When I start the activity I'm calling a third part package to show a calendar. When the user wants, the calendar is closed by pressing a button. finishActivity is in the method of the button. If I call finish, y close my application activity, not the calendar activity.

Comment: put finish(); to your TargetActivity OnCreate()

Comment: where you are writing finishActivity

Comment: "i've been trying this 2 days..." me too!! i feel the documentation is uncomplete about this... the most intuitive is to believe that the `finishActivity` method actually FINISHES the activity lol... just for the record, the `finishActivity` method does not finish the activity, just sets the request code... pretty confusing if you ask me n.n'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*finishActivity(...)* is used for something different than you might think. Its meant for when you want to finish the result yielding activity from the activity that launched it. Its counter intuitive but the docs are clear about it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishActivity(int)

What you need to do in your scenario is:

**Just use finish() after setResult(..., ...) in the activity you called for result.**

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtras(yourResultsBundle)
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `finishActivity` method merely sets the response code, so you have to call a `finish()` after calling the `finishActivity(CURRENT_ACTIVITY)` in order to finish the activity. And don't forget to call `setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent())` (in case your activity succeeded on sending the result) before finishing it.

In other words, you are not closing the activity if you just call `finishActivity`, you are only setting the result code... in order to actually close the activity, you have to call `finish` after `finishActivity`.

So the code to finish the activity should look something like this:

```
// ...
finishActivity(CURRENT_ACTIVITY);
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `finish();` after calling calendar intent.

```
Intent calendar = new Intent();
calendar.setPackage("com.digibites.calendar");
if (calendar.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(calendar);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: This close my main activity, not the calendar activity

Comment: finishActivity will do the same @edusan1213

Comment: no, CURRENT_ACTIVITY is the code of the calendar activity, so it will close this activity, not the main activity from wich im launching this. I have other activities programmed myself and i dont have this problem, the same code close perfectly all of them when the users wants, thats beacouse i suspect that is beacouse is a third part app

Comment: may be i dont have permission to control an activity of other application, in spite of i´ve launched this activity from my app...

Answer (score -1):

You can use finish(); instead of finishActivity(CURRENT_ACTIVITY);

Comment: this close my main activity, wich is running in background instead the calendar activity

Comment: Than use  CURRENT_ACTIVITY.this.finish();

Comment: CURRENT_ACTIVITY is an int variable, not a activity, so if a i write this shows me an error. CURRENT_ACTIVITY Is the request code that i put in startActivityForResult...

Comment: Than ues your Activity Name which u want to finish instead of CURRENT_ACTIVITY .
Is REQUEST_CALENDAR is Activity u want to finish.?
than use it instead of CURRENT_ACTIVITY.

Answer (score -1):

First use `finishActivity(requestcode);`
then use `finish();`